# Sobolev's inequality for C-continuous functions

Tags: normed-spaces, sobolev-spaces, finite-element-method

In [Strang's book on Finite Element Method](https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/000370983), the Sobolev's inequality is stated as followed: If $v$ is a function in $H^s$ and $s>n/2$, then $v$ is continuous and:

$$
\max \left| v(x_1, \cdots, x_n) \right| \leq C ||v||_s
$$

Do we have similar results for functions that are C-continuous, i.e. $v \in C^s$?

Comment: Can you please provide a definition of C-continuity?

Comment: @ktoi A function is said to be $C^k$ continuous if its k-th derivative is continuous. Is that what you want?

Comment: If the domain $\Omega$ is bounded then $C^s(\overline{\Omega})\subset H^s(\Omega)$.